# Pathway issue java

Tags: java, path

I have a piece of code I'm currently struggling with

```
System.out.println("What file would you like to open?");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String files = sc.nextLine();   
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(files));
```

Basically, let's say I have a file called text.txt and I enter that as user input for the scanner to analyze, where should it be placed in my directory? I tried to put it in the bin and src files of my class and inside my class also but I keep getting a  `FileNotFoundException` at the line:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(files));
```

It doesn't even ask me for any user input.

Comment: It has to be in the same folder as the folder that the `java` process was started in. If you're developing in Eclipse, that will be the Project directory.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis
Cheers that helps, but would you know why the program doesn't even ask me for the files and proceeds straight to a FileNotFoundException?

Comment: Is there any code you aren't showing us?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
String current = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

you can check where you are currently in.

You might try just putting it in the project root folder, one above src/bin.

Comment: I put it in both the project root folder and inside the src/bin and the program proceeds straight to a FileNotFoundException without even asking me for the input I tried to put in ; got any idea what I could do?

Comment: sc.nextLine() should be blocking and waiting for your input.
You might try debugging by just manually entering the file name in the code, to check if it actually would find the file.

Do you read from the scanner before? like sc.nextInt()
this would cause nextLine() to return with just a linebreak "\r\n"